# Strange results returning from Response.getId() in GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am working with a script to pull the response ID from a form submission so that when users edit their response, I can match the edit to the initial response.  My script creates a .pdf of the contents of each form submitted, but when users edit responses, it creates a new form containing only the edited data, without linking it to the initial response.

The edit response contains a timestamp and the edited information, and the timestamp is used with Response.getId(timestamp), iirc, and returns the ID of the form submission.  However, I am sometimes getting a very strange return, and I don't know where it comes from. The response is much shorter than a typical response ID (10-12 alphanumeric instead of 30+).  I will try to comeback and edit this question with the code, but I'm on a different log in at the moment, so I'll have to swap over and copy code and come back.  Running unit tests hasn't really helped, as I get the expected result most of the time.  It's just an occasional hiccup, but I have to find where the incorrect information is coming from.

```
function getResponseId(timestamp){
  var form = FormApp.openById('<formID>');
  if(typeof(timestamp) != 'number'){
    timestamp = new Date(timestamp);
  }
  var responses = form.getResponses(timestamp);
  var entryId = responses[0].getId();

  return entryId;
}
```

That's is. I suppose the if(typeof... may be throwing things off if it's passing in a Date string instead of the actual timestamp of entry, but I don't think so.  I'll double check it and debug it in the meantime, and if I answer my own question, I'll come back and fix it.

Comment: Have you had a chance to take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22509607/the-id-of-a-formresponse-when-a-response-is-submitted-is-different-when-you-list)? Have you tried obtaining an ID using a similar function to onFormSubmit as mentioned in the link above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm. Sounds like the same behavior. What I decided to do instead was to match the timestamps that are recorded, but you have to grab the stamps in the 3rd line of code, as the old stamp is overwritten quickly. I just subtracted oldTime from newTime, left a 5 sec window to match them, and that worked. I just haven't had a chance to post it yet, as I just got it working for new submissions, edits, and failed writes about an hour ago.

Comment: This is pretty much what I did, in the end.  I think I went with 5 seconds or something like that because the form I use might get a few submissions each day.  If it gets more than that, it's because the same user is putting in multiple entries, and it takes longer than 5 seconds to create a new form.