# FormResponse.getId() returns the wrong value right after the response is submitted

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms, google-sheets-api

I am writing a program that requires the ID of various google form responses. My program first creates the form object and gets the responses:

```
var form = FormApp.openByUrl("...");
var allResponses = form.getResponses();
```

If the form response is a few hours old, it isn't an issue:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(allResponses[102].getId()); 
//Displays the correct value, 2_ABaOnufSugrHZ4swdyqxJ5hCxyDuFCdO5F_5glYgHsFCZotI99MFMX1IjGK3EQ
```

The problem occurs when I'm using a newer response (a few minutes old):

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(allResponses[103].getId());
//Displays the wrong value, ChM3MDQ0MTQwMjIwNDQzOTcxNTczEO2B_fv-qeblbQ
```

Eventually, the second line displays the correct value, but it takes a little while. Is there a way to speed up this process?

Comment: Does the incorrect Id refer to anything (like another response, or the form itself)? Is it the same incorrect string every time?

Comment: The id refers to the form response itself. It returns one string for the first hour or so after a form is submitted and another string after that. @zaq

Comment: I tried it and it does look like a temporary id is given, seems to also start with 'ch' for me too. I found this post which may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22509607/the-id-of-a-formresponse-when-a-response-is-submitted-is-different-when-you-list